# Vagrant. VM after provisioning

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I tried to adopt Vagrant in our team. I created a Vagrantfile and make provisioning in some way. Everything works as charm, but ...

It's unclear for me how I can automate some routine tasks like:

- running django(I use django, but it's framework agnostic problem) dev server on 0.0.0.0
- running grunt watcher
- providing a separate console for django-specific commands

It is looks like vagrant not intended to help with this kind of automation and I look for some community adopted way to do that. I goggled and found nothing.

I see a few way to that:

- bootstrap.sh script but messy and hard to mantain
- something like tmuxinator -- requires tmux on host machine and now it's impossible to put tmuxconfig in project repo
- etc

What is the 'canonical' way to resolve this problem?

**P.S.:** Please, think about designers, manual testers and other guys which like to use tools as is

Answer (score 1):

In general you are best off using a provisioner. To be honest, a bootstrap.sh file is a good place to start unless you want to learn the ins and outs of something like chef / ansible / salt / puppet. If you do you might want to start at salt (SaltStack) because it is written in python which I'm guessing you use given the django angle.

For your specific questions:

- Part of the point of vagrant is it lets you develop against real stacks and real web servers so you can avoid the "oh, that don't quite work the same on apache" moment that often comes in projects. So for your first question I would look at how to provision the app behind apache / nginx or whatever you are using for the production web servers.
- Because of the shared file systems users can just run grunt locally on the host machine. This also lets grunt do things like hook into OSX notifications.
- I'm not familiar with tmuxinator so I'm not sure how to start here. But if it is a service that the server really runs then you should figure out a way to package the install and deploy it to the provisioned VM. As for configuration, is it possible to get a dev config in the repo?

Comment: Hi, consider this [example](https://github.com/kharandziuk/vagrant-django-initial). I'm already use a provisioner. The question how can I simplify using of vagrant for designers or manuals testers?
For example, every tester should run a django-server and grunt, but most of them know nothing about these technologies

Comment: Gr8, you start working on it. The repository shows you prefer the provision tool `ansible`, that's fine, then try to make it work. For designers or testers, they needn't know how to do that, for them, you just give commands to them to start the instance , such as `git clone`, `vagrant up`, `vagrant ssh`, that's all. You will be the contact to maintenant the repository.

Comment: @kharandziuk -- Yes, you can but you have to approach vagrant right. I hinted at that a bit in my answer -- you avoid having to fire off django-server by making the app run in the vagrant VM with a forwarded port. As for grunt you could hook it into the provisioning script so it happens when someone fires up the box which probably covers testers. Designers should be capable of firing it off IMHO. Does that clear things up a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Same as @Wyatt, I recommend use Vagrant with provision tools, such as `puppet, saltstack, chef, anisble`, etc. These tools are created for the requirements you ask for, and most are open source. Choice is no wrong, you can start learning from any one, they are similar.

With that, you can quickly and easily run several VM servers with all applications installed automatically.  With the customised Puppet codes or chef cookbooks, you can update them any time and provision to VM easily, you can re-use them for your PROD environment as well.

Take some times to learn one of these automation tools first, you will get benefit to save a lot of time.

I use Puppet, and recommend the best puppet book [PRO PUPPET](http://www.apress.com/9781430230571) to you. It has all you need.

[image: automation tools trends]

Comment: The final choice will be depended on yourself, if you can make the decision. All these provision tools are mature and developped and used by many years and by thousands and hundred clients in different industries area. Start from the familiar one will be easy for you. Otherwise, if you have no experience on any of them, then choice one of them and start learning first.

Comment: the question isn't about a provisioner tool.

Comment: @bmw Ansible is mispelled its messing up your comparison.